# Does applying a variable transformation to experiment data result in p-hacking?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-transformation, p-hacking

From formal statistics classwork and some research experience, I understand that it is widely considered standard practice to apply transformations to predictor variables for conducting significance tests in A/B test settings if their sampling distributions don't satisfy conditions of normality. However, based on some readings, I am wondering if these transformations when applied to skewed data are considered "variance reduction" variable transformations that are actually a form of p-hacking.

This [reference](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.220346), for example, conducts a simulation about how log, square root, and inverse transformations change the underlying measurement scale and result in higher false positive rates. Additional reading leads me to believe that selecting these transformations (and examining the data to check if they result in normal distributions) actually results in a reduction of the degrees of freedom. If this is the case, for large sample sizes ($> 1000$), does it matter if since the transformations will have a negligible impact on the $d.o.f$?

In summary, my main question is

**Can a monotonic transformation of a random variable result in achievement of significance (p < x) in transformed space when there was no significance in the original space?**

Comment: Identifying a transformation parameter costs you one degree of freedom.  That's nothing in a large sample, as you remark.  The answer to your main question is a definite yes, and examples abound, both theoretical and in the real world.  The proof is to take practically *any* dataset, make the transformation, and observe that the p-value changes.  *Ergo,* for any threshold of significance between those two p-values, there will be a change in significance effected by the transformation and its inverse.

Comment: Also, *predictors do not need to be normally distributed*. If you are one of my wife's students, please don't check predictors for normality, because it is a Bad Day in our household when she gets another thesis to grade that does this.

Comment: "Does applying a variable transformation to experiment data result in p-hacking?" Just applying one? No. Using the same data as you want to perform inference on to identify one and then applying that? Yes, at least somewhat. There's ways to avoid that, though, like not using the same observations for model identification and for inference. Depending on what kinds of things you're doing to identify a transformation / how large a class of transformations you consider, it may be multiple degrees of freedom, however.

Comment: I think it matters why you choose to transform variables. All statistical models have assumptions. For simple OLS you don't need residuals to be normally distributed, but for evaluation of standard error something like that might become necessary. This is what should drive the decision to transform variables - to have your data fit the assumptions of your model. For example, if you are planning to use assumption of normally distributed residuals, are they normally distributed? Note that this is not the same thing as doctoring transform to drag coefficient values into significance region